# SQL Append to VARCHAR Column failing with Truncate DOUBLE Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns

```
tick varchar(10), category varchar(100)
```

and they have the following 2 records (for sample)

```
EFG,0
XYZ,#
```

(EFG and XYZ) are values for tick column, and (0 and #) are for categories column, respectively.

My need is to append the string ',Cool,' (commas included) to the existing category value, so that the above two records become

```
"EFG","0,Cool,"
"XYZ","#,Cool,"
```

So I am running the following SQL statements:

```
update tablen set category = category + ',Cool,' where tick='EFG';
update tablen set category = category + ',Cool,' where tick='XYZ';
```

However, for the first SQL statement, it is not changing any value at all. For the second, the category value is updated from # to "0"

In both cases, I am getting warnings:

```
 Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '#' (and for '0')
 Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',Cool,'
```

Unable to understand why the VARCHAR column update is throwing a DOUBLE value error.

Can someone please shed some light on what am I doing wrong here? Is there any typecasting required?

Many Thanks

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Don't store lists of things in a comma-delimited string.  That is not the SQL way to store such things.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for the inputs. At times, there are certain requirements which need an unspecified number of items in a list (like a product falling under X number of categories.) That's what I'm using the CSV values for in a column. Do you have recommendations for any better implementations? Would love to have some valuable insights

Comment: You should use a junction/association table with one row per item and category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql the concat is not `+` but concat()

```
update tablen set category = concat(category , ',Cool,') where tick='EFG';
update tablen set category = concat(category , ',Cool,') where tick='XYZ';
```

the plus sign induce mysql to think that the values  are number  ..  but  you have varchar  ..

Comment: Thanks a lot @scaisEdge...Fixed the problem! Marking it as an answer and +1